# Load a 2D array on smarty html pages

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I'm trying to develop a Question&Answer website in php using Smarty framework. So far it is going smooth but I started to develop the comments part and I'm not getting how I can implement it.

- Question

  - Answer 1

    - Comment 1
    - Comment 2
    - Comment 3
  - Answer 2

    - Comment 1
    - Comment 2
    - Comment 3
  - Answer 3

    - Comment 1
    - Comment 2
    - Comment 3

This is my question structure. The answers part is pretty easy because it does not matter how I print it, I just need to get all the answers from a given questionid and show it in the question page. But when it comes to comments, it is different. 
How can I show the answers comments correctly? Do I need to create a 2D array where I have an array with answers and their comments?

```
<?php
include_once('../../../config/init.php');
include_once($BASE_DIR . 'database/questions.php');

increment_views_counter((int) $_GET['question']);

if($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
    $smarty->display('common/header_log.tpl');
} else {
    $smarty->display('common/narrow_header.tpl');
}

$questions = get_questions_from_id($_GET['question']);
$tags = get_tags_from_question($_GET['question']);
$question = $questions[0];
$question['isMine'] = question_is_mine($question);
$answers = get_answers_from_questionid($_GET['question']);

$smarty->assign('isMine', $question['isMine']);
$smarty->assign('tags', $tags);
$smarty->assign('answers', $answers);
$smarty->assign('question', $question);
$smarty->display('question.tpl');
$smarty->display('common/footer.tpl');
```

This is my pages/question.php . I get the question info I need, including the answers. Now, I need to get the comments for each answer and a way to show them on my template:

```
<div class="qa-a-list-item hentry answer">
                                            {foreach $answers as $answer}
                                                {include file="answers.tpl"}
                                            {/foreach}
                                            <!-- END qa-a-item-main -->
                                        </div>
```

And then I'd need to loop each answer and print all the comments. How and when should I load them? Should I gather all the comments when I load the question page?

Kind regards

Comment: "Do I need to create a 2D array where I have an array with answers and their comments?" have you tried this?